# How to get user console input into a Prolog list

Tags: list, input, prolog

I am trying to write the user input into a list but am running into two problems. Using this code

```
getInput([Symptom|List]):-
    writeln('Enter Element:'),
    read(Symptom),
    dif(Symptom,stop),
    getInput(List).
getInput([]).
```

I am able to get symptoms from the user but the output shows the first user input as the Head, and the others as the tail. How do I make the Head "Symptoms" and only ad the user input to the Tail? Secondly, when I change "stop" to "Done" the program no longer stops?

So I was told "Done" doesn't work because it is capitalized. If I want to use a capital word, how would I do that?

Comment: `Done` is a variable because it starts with an upper case letter and `stop` is not because it does not start with and upper case letter.

Comment: @GuyCoder ok thank you. So how would i use dif to stop when "Done" is entered and not "done"?

Comment: What happens if you have a symptom that has the same name as your `EOF`, either "stop" or "Done" or whatever, really? The user will never be able to enter that symptom.

Comment: @repeat Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
get_symptoms(Symptoms) :-
    write('Enter Symptom: ' ),
    read_string(user, "\n", "\r", _, Response),
    (
        Response == "Stop"
    ->
        Symptoms = []
    ;
        get_symptoms(Symptoms0),
        Symptoms = [Response|Symptoms0]
    ).
```

Uses
   1. [==/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%3D%3D/2) instead of [dif/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=dif/2).
   2. [read_string/5](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read_string/5) instead of [read/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read/1) so that strings can be entered.
   3. [write/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=write/1) instead of [writeln/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=writeln/1) so that input is on same line as prompt.
   4. [->/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=-%3E/2) instead of separate clauses.

You can change the value of the exit word to something other than "Stop", you can even use single characters like "." if you like.

Notice also that this does not require a cut (!).

Example runs:

```
?- get_symptoms(List).
Enter Symptom: Stop
List = [].

?- get_symptoms(List).
Enter Symptom: A
Enter Symptom: Stop
List = ["A"].

?- get_symptoms(List).
Enter Symptom: a
Enter Symptom: A
Enter Symptom: A line with some spaces
Enter Symptom: Notice that a period is not needed at the end
Enter Symptom: Stop
List = ["a", "A", "A line with some spaces", "Notice that a period is not needed at the end"].
```

---

> How do I make the Head "Symptoms" and only add the user input to the Tail?

You want to make the user input the head and have the following entries as the tail. The trick for this example is to put the list constructor `|/2`  after the recursive call, e.g.

```
    get_symptoms(Symptoms0),           % Recursive call
    Symptoms = [Response|Symptoms0]    % List constructor
```

> Secondly, when I change "stop" to "Done" the program no longer stops?

Since `Done` starts with a capital letter it is a Prolog variable which is causing the problem. `stop` starts with a lower case letter and is an atom so works as expected with the compare.

> If I want to use a capital word, how would I do that?

You can use [read/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read/1) which requires the user to input "" when entering the value, e.g.

```
?- read(X).
|: "Hello".

X = "Hello".
```

but [read/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read/1) reads a term so requires the user to not only add the double quotes but end with a period. Using [read_string/5](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read_string/5) allows the user to enter data as they would expect. The input will be read and stored as a string. If the data is then to be converted there are predicates that operate on [strings](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=string-predicates)

Comment: This was a lot of help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
get_input( Rs ) :-
  get_input( [], Rs )
  .

get_input( Ss , Rs ) :-
  writeln('Enter Element:'),
  read( S ),
  dif( S , stop ),
  !,
  get_input( [S|Ss] , Rs )
  .
get_input( Rs, Rs ).
```