# Read user input and assign string matching result to parameter

Tags: prolog

I need to write a predicate that reads user input. If the input is "yes" (ideally "yes or "y") it must assign yes to the parameter, if it is any different it must assign no.

```
askContinue(Answer) :-
    write("Would you like to continue ?  "), read(Input), nl,
    (Input = "yes" -> Answer = true ; Answer = false).
```

The output is:

```
?- askContinue(A).
Would you like to continue ? yes.

A = false.

?- askContinue(A).
Would you like to continue ? no.

A = false.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Works for me, if you change the type of Input, i.e. check whether Input = yes without quotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Write User Input to a List Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677190/how-to-write-user-input-to-a-list-prolog)

Comment: thanks @GuyCoder. It's a great answer and it's close to what I needed but it does not fully answer the question since it does not explain how to conditionally assign a value to the parameter based on the result of a string matching operation (memberchk in TA_intern answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is that you are comparing the atom that you read using `read` with a string. Instead, compare it to an atom (single quotes or no quotes):

```
askContinue(Answer) :-
    write("Would you like to continue ?  "), read(Input), nl,
    (Input = yes -> Answer = true ; Answer = false).
```

You can use something else instead of `read`. Maybe you don't want to have to type in "`.`" after your answer. If you read until Enter is pressed:

```
ask(Prompt, Answer) :-
    prompt1(Prompt),
    read_string(current_input, "\n", " \t", _Sep, Response),
    response_answer(Response, Answer).

response_answer(Response, Answer) :-
    string_lower(Response, R),
    (   memberchk(R, ["y", "yes"])
    ->  Answer = yes
    ;   Answer = no
    ).
```

This will correctly recognize "Yes", "yes", "y", "Y" and so on.

```
?- ask("Would you like to continue? ", Answer).
Would you like to continue? Y
Answer = yes.

?- ask("Would you like to continue? ", Answer).
Would you like to continue? Yeah
Answer = no.
```

Comment: Finally a read input that suggest to use [read_string/5](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read_string/5) before [read/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read/1)

Comment: However this is probably a duplicate question because I have been suggesting to use read_string/5 for quite some time.